# Does the SQL COUNT function automatically exclude NULL values?

Tags: sql, count

I have a database called people with a total of 8398 records. I know this because I have performed the following query with the COUNT function.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM people;
```

However, when I perform a COUNT on the birthdate column I find that this only returns 6152 records. Is this because the COUNT function is automatically excluding NULL values in the birthdate column?

```
SELECT COUNT(birthdate)
FROM people;
```

How could I perform a count of all the columns that are NULL in the birthday column?

Comment: `COUNT(expr)` counts the number of rows that have `expr` being evaluated to not `NULL`.

Comment: `select count(birthdate) from people where birthdate is not null`

Comment: @WillardSolutions semantically it's the same though. And most likely it's the same performance wise.

Comment: Could someone provide an answer as opposed to comments?

Comment: @user1554264 it's not clear what you're asking: your latest query does exactly what you asked.

Comment: @user1554264 What exactly is your question that hasn't been answered in the comments?

Comment: @zerkms I have sinced ammended my answer - I'm sorry for the confusion

Comment: `select count(1) from people where birthdate is null`

Comment: Or `SELECT COUNT(*)` (which is more idiomatic and for some DBMS might be more performant)

Comment: I have opted to use `SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM people
WHERE birthdate is NULL;` - This seems to have achieved the desired result in simple syntax.

Answer (score 2):

> How could I perform a count of all the columns that are NULL in the
>   birthday column?

Check if column is null using CASE expression:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN birthdate IS NULL THEN 1 END)
FROM people;
```

The expression evaluates to 1 when `birthdate` is null, and evaluates to NULL when `brthdate` is not null. Since COUNT counts only not null values, you will get a number of NULLs in `birthdate` column.

Comment: Hi I have opted to use  `SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM people
WHERE birthdate is NULL; ` as this seems to have achieved the result that I wanted.